# LWC - trying to create a combobox from JSON response

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, json

**(Updated code)** - thanks, [@sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox)

I have been stuck on this for many hours now, I really hope someone can share an insight:

I have a combobox, and I wish to populate it with the values at this API endpoint:
https://bitpay.com/api/rates

So, the format of the JSON is:

{"code":"BTC","name":"Bitcoin","rate":1}

For the combobox, the label will be the "name" field, and the value will be the rate field.

I've tried passing this information to LWC in many formats - an object(with String, Decimal fields), as a Map<String,String> - always with the same result.

The frustrating thing is that the combobox is being populated with 183 rows, but they are all blank.

I have tried various methods of JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) each of the fields, but cannot get them to display. If anyone was able to help me with this, you would have my eternal gratitude - thanks guys

Oh, and btw was following this tutorial (have also tried a few others)
http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2019/07/display-lwc-combobox-event-propagaton.html

bitcoin2.html

```
<template>
  <lightning-card
    title="List of Contacts - Lightning Web Component"
    icon-name="custom:custom63"
  >
    <lightning-combobox
      name="currencies"
      label="Currencies"
      placeholder="Choose a currency"
      value={value}
      onchange={handleChange}
      options={statusOptions}
    >
    </lightning-combobox>
    Selected Rate: {selectedRate}
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

bitcoin2.js

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class BitCoin2 extends LightningElement {
  //bitcoin_rates;
  statusOptions = [];
  selectedRate = "None";
  connectedCallback() {
    const URL = "https://bitpay.com/api/rates";
    fetch(URL, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then((responseJSON) => {
        this.statusOptions = JSON.parse(responseJSON.data).map(
          ({ name: label, rate: value }) => ({ value, label })
        );
      });
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.selectedRate = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown what the wrappers look like, but regardless, I think you're overthinking things.

Here's my take on how to handle this:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String getCurrencies() {
  Http http = new Http();
  HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
  request.setEndpoint('https://bitpay.com/api/rates');
  request.setMethod('GET');
  HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
  if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    return response.getBody();
  }
  return '[]';
}
```

No wrapper required. As far as the far end, having already deserialized once, you don't need to reserialize and re-deserialize again either.

```
@wire(getCurrencies) handleCurrencyResult(result) {
  if(result.data) {
    this.statusOptions = JSON.parse(result.data).map(
      ({name: label, rate: value})=>({value, label})
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to keep the wrappers, you can, it's just not terribly efficient to do so for something as simple as three variables.

Edit: We can't use `List<Map<String, Object>>`, so it's actually better to just return the string directly and parse it client-side. I'll update the demo to reflect this. Also, methods that are used in wires must be `cacheable=true`, as demonstrated above.

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/1AiQSxsGCDy2obShRzEJ/src/app.html?p=stories).

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question - I never new about the Map<String,Object> to store a JSON result.

I hope this isn't a silly question - I tried to implement your answer (using the List<Map<String, Object>> getCurrencies() apex method, and not using the getCurrencies.js file, which I presume it replaces) and am now getting an empty selector that is not displaying any options :(

Do you know why this might be? The component is exposed, and is saving/deploying with no error, but the selector is still not displaying anything.

Comment: @ElTttt Edit your question to include the latest code, then mention me `@sfdcfox` and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks a million @sfdcfox  have updated the code now

Comment: @ElTttt Nothing immediately pops out, but let me play with this in a dev org. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @ElTttt Spoke too soon. You put the `@AuraEnabled` on the class, not the method. Change that, and you should be good.

Comment: Hey - thanks, but this was actually and error when putting the code up here, the method was already @AuraEnabled, so unfortunately it was not this :(
 - have updated the code in the question now, apologies for any confusion

Comment: @ElTttt No worries, I'll play with it.

Comment: thanks again, really appreciate it

Comment: @ElTttt I just forgot a few things. I've been distracted all week, but I tested this latest version, it works fine.

Comment: It's strange - when I deployed the component to the page, I got a 'data.map is not a function' error. This went away by itself after adding and then deleting some text and redeploying to the server; however I am still getting a 'LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
["undefined" is not valid JSON]' 

When I do a system.debug of the apex method, I get a really short string containing only the first couple of hundred characters from the response; I suppose this isn't normal(?)
Thanks again for all the time you have taken on

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox - I tried to simplify things by using a connectedCallback() to get the data into the component. I am still getting an empty selector  _ I'm sure that the problem is somewhere around:

 ' JSON.parse(responseJSON.data)'   or

 'return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then((responseJSON) => ' 

 - I'm not really sure how to debug that

Comment: @ElTttt I created an [Unlocked Package](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t1U000007kP8AQAU) for you to experiment with. Please feel free to install this in a sandbox, scratch org, developer edition, whichever, browse the code, and compare it with your own.

Comment: It's working! you are a legend among men, the whole Salesforce ecosystem would collapse without your contributions on this board, man! -  thanks so much for all of your help this weekend.

Comment: @ElTttt hahaha, hyperbole much? Still, I'm glad I was able to help!